# Search in LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, interface

Let's have this code :

```
class student :IComparable , IComparable<student> 
{
    public string name = "";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name; 
    }

    #region IComparable Members

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (this.name.Equals(((student)obj).name ) )
            return 0 ; 
        else
            return -1 ; 
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparable<student> Members

    public int CompareTo(student other)
    {
        if (this.name.Equals (other.name )) 
            return 0 ; 
        else
            return -1 ; 
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I am create LinkedList from this class in Main Like :

```
LinkedList<student> list = new LinkedList<student>(); 
list.AddLast(new student { name="Farah"}); 
list.AddLast(new student { name="Noor"}); 
list.AddLast(new student { name="Reem"});

foreach (student s in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

it's print :
Farah 
Noor 
REEM

but when I am try to search about any element it doesn't find it , Like :

```
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(new student{ name="Noor"}));
```

This Print false although "student" class implements "IComparable , IComparable" !!

What should I do to work  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, that Contains doesn't works with IComparable interface. It uses Equals method. SO override it:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.CompareTo(((IComparable)obj)) == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why the cast to `IComparable`?

Comment: @dalle - just to make dramatic accent :)

Comment: Casting to `Student` would be more appropriate, and saves a minuscule of instructions.

Comment: @dalle - because Dewfy used CompareTo method :)

Comment: @Farah_online: The parameter to `IComparable.CompareTo` is of type `object`. The parameter to `IComparable<T>.CompareTo` is of type `T`. Casting to `IComparable` makes no sense, but of course `IComparable` is convertible to `object`. Casting to `Student` would result in the `IComparable<Student>.CompareTo` method being called, which then "saves" one cast, alas the saving of a minuscule of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) for your student class.

- [Guidelines for Implementing Equals and the Equality Operator (==)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx%28VS.71%29.aspx)